Observe only affected rows in Room Database table android with LiveData
I have one room database table, and I have query as
@Query("Select * from message WHERE myId = :myId AND createdAt NOTNULL ORDER BY createdAt DESC")
fun getAllMessagesByRoomId(myId: Int): LiveData<List<ChatMessagePojo>>

current scenario :
When there is one new entry in this table, The observer receives the list of all rows,
When there is update in any column, observer still receives the list of all rows in this table.
But I want the affected rows only.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Before you deep-dive into InvalidationTracker, are you sure you actually need that? Why is it so important to only get the difference and not the final result? When you get a new set of result data you can still compare the entries for changes. When properly set up Compose's LazyColumn, for example, does this automatically for you and can display a neat animation for the changed elements.
